# Symfony - set empty string instead null

Tags: php, string, symfony, symfony4

In my Symfony `4.4` project I have entity field defined:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default":""})
 */
protected $name = '';
```

I want to set a property property to the empty string `''`, and not to `null`.

When I have name filed already set and I want to revert it back to empty string how can I accomplish that within setter in some method?

For example:

```
$names = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Names::class)
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

$names->setName('');      |----> would this be right solution?

$this->entityManager->persist($names);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: first, if you are updating an already existing entity, persisting doesn't do anything useful; try to set the `nullable=false` on the property - it looks okay otherwise

Comment: Yes, that works. You could also have a `function resetName() { $this->name = ''; }` in your model to make this more expressive by calling `$names->resetName()` instead of `setName('')`, but your method will probably work best with forms, api-platform and other tools that utilize getters/setters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @dbrumann